# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)

Tags: c++

```
//Definition of pushTop()
void Staque::pushTop(const StaqueElement & value)
{
    myTop = new Staque::Node(value, myTop);
    count++;
}

//Definition of pushBottom()
void Staque::pushBottom(const StaqueElement & value)
{
    if (empty()==1)
    {
        myBottom=new Staque::Node(value);
        myTop->next=myBottom;
        count++;
    }

    myBottom->next = new Staque::Node(value);
    myBottom = myBottom->next;
    count++;
}
```

my pushTop function works fine but every time I try to enter an odd number I get this error

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)" in line 18 
>   "myBottom->next = new Staque::Node(value);"

I am trying to add an integer to a linked list. Even numbers go to the top while odd numbers go to the bottom of the list.

Comment: If `empty() == 1` you appear to be creating 2 nodes and incrementing the count twice. Is that correct? And if it's empty, surely `myTop` won't be pointing anywhere? Hard to say without the rest of the code.

Comment: Can you give us enough code to replicate the error?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if this is the only problem from the code you have provided, but you also need to set `myBottom` in the `pushTop(...)` method.  If you don't do this, then `empty()` may be false, but `myBottom` will be invalid when calling `pushBottom(...)`.

Something like this:

```
//Definition of pushTop()
void Staque::pushTop(const StaqueElement & value)
{
    myTop = new Staque::Node(value, myTop);
    if (empty())
        myBottom = myTop;
    count++;
}
```

Note also that I think you need to modify `myBottom(...)` too, as it will add two elements if called when the stack is empty:

```
//Definition of pushBottom()
void Staque::pushBottom(const StaqueElement & value)
{
    if (empty())
    {
        myBottom = new Staque::Node(value);
        myTop->next = myBottom;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        myBottom->next = new Staque::Node(value);
        myBottom = myBottom->next;
        count++;
    }
}
```

An alternative might be:

```
//Definition of pushBottom()
void Staque::pushBottom(const StaqueElement & value)
{
    if (empty())
        pushTop(value);
    else
    {
        myBottom->next = new Staque::Node(value);
        myBottom = myBottom->next;
        count++;
    }
}
```